# service to check if exchange is sending receiving email?

Tags: exchange-2007, network-monitoring

I need of a web service that check if my exchange is sending receiving email properly.
And if there are some problem it sends a sms to my cellular. I don't want an app because I have not a smartphone.
it should just send an email to test@mydomain.com and then it connect to my exchange/owa to download it. Once every hour.
I have found many software like nagios and so on but I need something that is outside my lan.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a set of real end-users, they're almost always better than a monitoring service. I manage quite a few mail systems (mostly Exchange), and *any* sort of outage immediately spurs phone calls and inquiries about *whether the mail server is down.|when it'll be back?|where is my email?|**I'll kill you!***

This is one case where I don't do anything proactively from a monitoring perspective to see if Exchange is "up", since there are a number of moving pieces involved. Add the fact that there's some resiliency built into the SMTP protocol, and I think it's just not necessary to go out of your way for this...